# How to easily maintain the RMI interfaces across multiple applications like server and client?

Tags: java, interface, rmi

Any one dealing with the RMI would certainly have come across this dilemma of how to easily maintain the interfaces to objects providing remote method invocation service to other client applications. Whenever we decide to have a minor change in the method declaration or adding/deleting methods declared in the interface, we have to manually replicate the change in all the clients that would be using that interface for accessing RMI service from a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Think about having a downloadable (Serializable) agent that has a more stable interface used by the client, and that uses the remote interface to do its job. You can use the codebase feature to ensure its availability to all clients. The agent needs to contain the stub. You can bind the agent to the Registry, or return it from some other remote method.

Or, use JWS to distribute new versions of the clients.

Or, design your remote interfaces more stably so they don't have to change -:)

Comment: By serializable agent, do you mean to having a one extra layer of abstraction in RMI which will lead a hierarchical service model? If that is the case, then it might open up some new options in terms of application architecture at design level I guess. Thanks for pointing out that, and correct me if you mean something else...

Answer (score 0):

One of the good workaround I came up with is to

1. put all the interfaces provided by the RMI server in a separate
   project which will pack itself into a jar file when built.
2. Then just add that jar file as dependency or in the
   classpath of the server application which is meant to provide the
   RMI service as well as to any of the client applications that
   want to use those    interfaces for invoking remote methods.

This will ease the task of maintaining RMI interfaces by updating them at just one place. Extra effort of changing method signature in some interface will be limited to changing the application code which calls that method.